# Why Stream.generate use non-variance, but Optional.orElseGet use Covariance in Java 8

Tags: java, generics, covariance

For Java 8 source code in `Stream` class:

```
public static<T> Stream<T> generate(Supplier<T> s) {
        ...
}
```

In `Optional` class

```
public T orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> other) {
    ...
}
```

I already read this post: [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), but I have some confusison.

Why `generate` method parameter(`Supplier<T> s`) use **non-variance**, but `orElseGet` method parameter(`Supplier<? extends T> other`) use **Covariance**, how to decide use **Covariance** or **non-variance**?

Comment: The main difference is that for Optional's case, T is already fixed by the original Optional value.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Java developers agreed with you that `generate` should accept `Supplier<? extends T>`, as it was changed in Java 9. See [JDK-8132097 (Stream.generate should use a covariant Supplier as parameter)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8132097):

> ###### Description
>
> The signature of Stream.generate doesn't to use a wildcard (? extends) hence some programs are rejected even if they are valid.
> The signature should be public static Stream generate(Supplier<? extends T> s).

The change makes sense, as doing something like the this:

```java
Stream<CharSequence> stream = Stream.generate(new Supplier<String>() {
    @Override public String get() {
      // implementation...
    }
});
```

Should be perfectly valid. Admittedly, that is a very contrived example, but the point stands: The `Supplier` should be allowed to be parameterized with any subtype of `T`. And to relate this to PECS, the `Supplier` is functioning as a producer of `T`.

Comment: but why **Stream.collect** `<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator, BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);`  not use **Covariance**?

Comment: I can't give a positive answer, because I wasn't involved in the development process for streams. However, my guess is that it was either an oversight or that they thought it was unnecessary; given typical usage of streams, it's likely rare that the fact covariance is not used would actually cause a problem. But there also might be some obscure problem with type resolution if they used `? extends R` everywhere, not sure (or maybe there _was_ a problem in Java 8, but it may no longer be a problem now as type inference has been improved over time).

Comment: To speculate why it wasn't changed along with `generate`, it may simply be that no one has submitted a bug report for `collect`. Though the fact `generate` is a static method, and thus cannot be overridden, may make it easier to change without breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful to me. `Stream.collect()` is still keep **non-variance** in **Java17**. I don't know why.